# Is it advisable to upload files as parameter of Parse Cloud Code function?

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I want to upload videos to parse server. Instead of saving the video file with the Parse iOS SDK's `PFFile` I upload the video to Parse Cloud Code as parameter:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "uploadVideo", withParameters: ["videoData": videoData]]) { (response, error) in
    ...
}
```

On the server side I save the file:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("uploadVideo", function(request, response) {

    var videoData = request.params.videoData;
    var videoFile = new Parse.File("video.mov", videoData, "video/mov");

    videoFile.save(null, {useMasterKey: true})
    .then(
        function() {
            response.success();
        }, 
        function(error) {
            response.error(error.message);
        }
    );
});
```

Is that good practice or are there any risks involved?
E.g. what is the maximum data object size to be passed as Cloud Code parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to upload the file with `PFFile` and send the file object to the Cloud Code function as parameter. Unlike `PfObject` which cannot be passed as Cloud Code function parameter, `PFFile` can.

The advantage is that `PFFile` has an upload progress callback to give an upload status feedback to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I had some data issues with this, since my app may be used while trying to upload pictures in remote areas with poor service and no wifi. I changed the implementation to instead safe the Parse File object, and pass the URL if necessary, rather than sending a file. That way an unsuccessful file upload didn't interfere with the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Jake, can you elaborate further? Poor network service would affect any form of communication with the server, no matter which way you try to upload.

Comment: Yes but I didn't want the cloud function to depend on the file's successful upload, as it had other integral functionality included, and while the picture was important to receive eventually, was not integral to capturing a charge and marking a service as completed. So, we do the core business functionality with just a few small pieces of data, and have the file save trigger another function to attach the file to the object it needs to be on.

Comment: I understand, because you'd pass other parameters with the same call.